# Escape special chars with their entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have small requirement for escaping the special chars with respective entities, but I'm stuck with *apostrophe* and *backslash symbols*, showing error like incorrect syntax. and I'm using [Datatables version 1.9](https://datatables.net/new/1.9).

```
{
  "fnRender": function ( o, val ) {
    return String(val)
      .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
      .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
      .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
      .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
      .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
      .replace(/'/g, '&apos;')
      .replace(/\/g, '&bsol');
},
```

Could any one help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a semicolon at the end of this line : `.replace(/'/g, '&apos;');`. I think this is the reason why the *backslash* doesn't work. Fix this and then we'll see if you still have the *apostrophe* problem.

Comment: @Rajasekhar — Try putting code that actually reflects your problem in the question.

Comment: My bad, I couldn't know. Avoid typo on source code if you want proper help.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character in a regular expression. If you want to use it as data then you have to escape it. `/\\/g`.

Nothing is wrong with your apostrophe handling other than your attempt to convert it to an XML entity on the last line will never trigger since you converted them all to HTML entities in your third replace statement already.